# Is rename required by standard to be atomic?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

An interesting question arose while I was trying to answer this:

**[Is mv atomic on my fs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322038/is-mv-atomic-on-my-fs/322074#322074)**

Is the `rename()` function *required* to be atomic by standard?

The 'rationale' section of the [POSIX standard for `rename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) states:

> This `rename()` function is equivalent for regular files to that
>   defined by the ISO C standard. Its inclusion here expands that
>   definition to include actions on directories and specifies behavior
>   when the new parameter names a file that already exists. **That
>   specification requires that the action of the function be atomic.**

But, the [latest publicly-available ISO C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section on `rename`, in its entirety, states:

> **7.21.4.2 The `rename` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int rename(const char *old, const char *new);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `rename` function causes the file whose name is the string pointed to by `old` to be henceforth known by the name
>   given by the string pointed to by `new`. The file named `old` is no
>   longer accessible by that name. If a file named by the string pointed
>   to by `new` exists prior to the call to the `rename` function, the
>   behavior is implementation-defined.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `rename` function returns zero if the operation succeeds, nonzero if it fails, in which case if the file existed
>   previously it is still known by its original name.

There's no explicit requirement of any kind for any type of atomicity in the `rename()` section of the ISO C Standard.

Having written many programs that relied upon the apparently implementation-specific atomicity of `rename()`, I had assumed that atomicity was a requirement and was surprised by the lack in the C Standard.

But the POSIX standard says that the ISO C standard requires `rename()` to be atomic.

Explanation(s)?

Comment: You might want to include footnote 269. The paragraph titled **"Returns"** could be interpreted as implying atomicity, and that notion is further supported by note 269.

Comment: Does `rename` copy the file between different filesystems? If not, I'd expect it to use hard links where available, making the operation indeed atomic at application level. If it is atomic at FS or media-level is another question.

Comment: That's not what the POSIX standard says. "That specification" refers to "expands that definition to include actions on directories and specifies behavior when the new parameter names a file that already exists", i.e., the POSIX standard's additions. In particular, "If the link named by the *new* argument exists, [...] a link named *new* shall remain visible to other threads throughout the renaming operation and refer either to the file referred to by *new* or *old* before the operation began."

Comment: @T.C. The POSIX standard states "This `rename()` function is equivalent for regular files to that defined by the **ISO C standard.  ... That specification requires that the action of the function be atomic.**"  That's pretty unequivocal.  The POSIX standard states that the ISO C standard requires `rename()` to be atomic.  But as far as I can tell, there's *nothing* in the ISO C standard that *requires* atomicity.  Yet the POSIX standard states the ISO C standard requires that atomicity.  Hence the question.

Comment: I can use ellipsis too: "Its inclusion here ... **specifies** behavior when the new parameter names a file that already exists. **That specification** requires that the action of the function be atomic."

Comment: @T.C. So find "atomic" or some such with respect to `rename()` in the ISO C standards.  Else what is "that specification" referring to?

Comment: The additional specification in the POSIX standard?

Comment: @T.C. If the POSIX standard is referring to itself, that means that, in the *simpler* case of the target file not existing, `rename()` has no requirement to be atomic. Again, the question: Is `rename()` in general *required* to be atomic?  If that's qualified with "only if the target path already exists", than the answer should be no, I'd think.

Comment: @user3386109 I don't know how that footnote could do that. I'd think copying a file is hard to require atomicity on.  (Footnote 269 reads:   "Among the reasons the implementation may cause the
`rename`
function to fail are that the file is open
or that it is necessary to copy its contents to effectuate its renaming.")  Unless you're relying on the *negative* implications of that footnote? That seems hard to stretch to a general *requirement* that `rename()` be atomic. Could you follow up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your quote from the POSIX standard for [`rename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) comes from the (non-normative) 'Rationale' section.  The main entry — the actual normative material — begins:

> For rename(): <sup>[CX]</sup> [image: [Option Start]]  The functionality described on this reference page is aligned with the ISO C standard. Any conflict between the requirements described here and the ISO C standard is unintentional. This volume of POSIX.1-2008 defers to the ISO C standard. [image: [Option End]]
>
> The `rename()` function shall change the name of a file. The `old` argument points to the pathname of the file to be renamed. The `new` argument points to the new pathname of the file. <sup>[CX]</sup> [image: [Option Start]]  If the `new` argument does not resolve to an existing directory entry for a file of type directory and the `new` argument contains at least one non-`<slash>` character and ends with one or more trailing `<slash>` characters after all symbolic links have been processed, `rename()` shall fail.
>
> … [image: [Option End]]

All the rest of the entry is within the `[CX]` (C Extension) tag and discusses other special behaviours.

The rationale you quote says:

> This `rename()` function is equivalent for regular files to that defined by the ISO C standard. Its inclusion here expands that definition to include actions on directories and specifies behavior when the new parameter names a file that already exists. That specification requires that the action of the function be atomic.

The 'That specification' referred to in the last sentence is the expanded definition that includes the specification of the actions on directories and 'when the new parameter names a file that already exists', not the specification in the C standard which, as you observe, does not say anything about atomicity (very reasonably; there are systems that can support C and `rename()` without being able to support POSIX's more stringent atomicity requirement).

And I see that this is exactly the argument made by [T.C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538241/is-rename-required-by-standard-to-be-atomic#comment68316147_40538241) — I agree with T.C.

Comment: Thank you.  So the answer is "No, `rename()` isn't required to be atomic."  That makes sense - but I asked the question because I'd always *assumed* `rename` had to be atomic, and was surprised when I couldn't find that.  And it's always hard to prove a negative.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Correct, Standard C does not require `rename()` to be atomic.  POSIX has more stringent (and detailed and complete) rules because it deals with more file types. Standard C doesn't even know what a directory or symlink or FIFO is, let alone how they interact with `rename()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Not quite right - Standard C doesn't require `rename` to be atomic, *but POSIX does*.  The key sentence is "If the link named by the new argument exists, it shall be removed and old renamed to new. In this case, a link named new shall remain visible to other threads throughout the renaming operation and refer either to the file referred to by new or old before the operation began."

Comment: That makes it atomic when renaming to an existing filename. But what about renaming to a filename that doesn't already exist? There doesn't seem to be anything in POSIX that requires this to be atomic.